# using jQuery to load a php file and the php file includes

Tags: php, jquery, load

This may be a "stupid" question but ...

If I use JQuery .load(); etc to load a page into a  is there a way that I can pass a php config file data to it without having to redeclare it?  At the moment I am having to load the config files etc into the loaded page as well as on the page it loads into.

e.g.

In the head of page1.php - require('config.php');
then if I load page2.php into a  on page1 I have to call config.php on page2.php aswell but is there a way that I don't have to?

Comment: Sounds more like PHP issue than jQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, you're talking about a client request to get part of a page, loading part of the initial page that may have server-side variable *really* isn't what `.load()` is designed for.